Sybase ASE vs SQL Server trigger difference, how to work around
We are migrating from ASE (12.5) to SQL Server.
In our insert and update triggers, we have the code
IF UPDATE(Colname)
<do stuff>

on ASE, this is only returning true on updates of colName, ON SQL Server it returns true on update AND insert of colName.
Is there a code change we made to the trigger, to make SQL Server behave the same as ASE?
Maybe something like?
if UPDATE(Colname) and not INSERT(colName)

At my work they don't want a separate trigger for Insert and Update, they want to modify the insert and update trigger to behave like on ASE.
I proposed in SQL Server adding a small insert and separate small update trigger, and a 3rd trigger with table specific logic carried over from ASE... They are treating it as a last resort, only... to be avoided at all costs... Thus why I'm here.
I'm hoping for help creating a SQL Server trigger that behaves like the ASE trigger.

sorry, but in SQL Server you can distinguish trigger action INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE

Also, just incase you didn't know, UPDATE(<Column Name>) doesn't mean "If the column's value changed", it means "If the column was targeted as part of the UPDATE". UPDATE dbo.SomeTable SET SomeColumn = SomeColumn; would cause UPDATE(SomeColumn) to return TRUE, while UPDATE(Other column) would return FALSE.

can you post how the rest of the trigger look? or at least the general concept you're using? Usually UPDATE(...) is not needed at all on sql server

"they want to modify the insert and update trigger to behave like on ASE" then that would be to have separate triggers... The statement conflicts. It's like saying "I don't want my car to be red, I want it to be blue but have people think it's colour red". You can't change how people understand colours, just like you can't make T-SQL (in SQL Server) act like it's a different version of the dialect.

I don't know much about sybase but couldn't you say IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted) { this is an insert, so don't check IF UPDATE } ELSE { this is an update }? Obviously not with curly braces, just as pseudo logic. Of course, the other possibility is, change the trigger as part of the changeover to work correctly in the new platform rather than trying to make it straddle both.

The more logical positive test is IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted) AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted) { it's an update! }. But as Thom mentioned, that doesn't mean that the value of whatever column you're checking in IF (UPDATE) actually has a new value. If you only want to act on the case where the value has actually changed, you need to compare the values in inserted and deleted for each row, and don't forget to handle NULL on either side.

I sense a tension between the row count checks on the inserted and deleted virtual tables to infer insert or update operations and the merge statement. It works... currently.

"At my work they don't want a separate trigger for Insert and Update, they want to modify the insert and update trigger to behave like on ASE." - I'd argue your coworkers are wrong and they should adapt to change - their objection sounds rooted in aesthetics rather than any technical or engineering reason - and it's generally a bad idea to try to force one product/system to behave like another (c.f. people writing C++ like it's Java, or vice-versa). SQL Server's triggers are designed such that when different logic for insert vs. update is required then separate triggers should be used.

This is kind of hacky.
If you have a primary key column that never gets updated (e.g. an auto-incrementing ID) you can do this to detect changes to the column while excluding inserts:
UPDATE(Colname) and not UPDATE( [PK_column] )

Otherwise you have to do what @testing-ma-lady suggested in the comments.
